# How to POST values to two different PHP pages

Tags: php, mysql, post, php-7

I have made a login page using PHP and MySQL, when I log in, it POST's the users login details to a LoginCheck.php page where it checks these values with the ones in the database, if they don't match up, the user is returned to the login.php page, but if they are correct, they are taken to the home.php page.  I now want to be able to access these login details again on the home.php page, but I can't find a way to post through two pages, or to two different ones? the POST vales come out as blank on the home.php page when I try to call them.

My code below for how i POST the user login details to the LoginCheck.php page via HTML,

```
<form method ="POST" action="LoginCheck.php">

<div class="form-input">

    <b> User Name <b><br />
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" />
    <br />

    <b> Password <b><br />
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
    <br />

<input type="submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn-login"/>
```

I have also tried AJAX to pass this value, but it also returns the same error

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit').click(function(){
            alert("is working");
            var user = $('#user').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            var userData = 'user=' + user + '&password=' + password;            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:'home.php',
                data: userData,
                success: function(){
                    alert("has passed data");
                }
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

Ideally i'd like to have the values POST from the LoginCheck page on loading, as this page is only visible for a couple of seconds to the user.

I get the error: Notice: Undefined index: user and Notice: Undefined index: password when I call them via POST in Home.php

Comment: What purpose would you have to access the users login details again? Using POST variables are not the way to go here, as they are removed with each new request, perhaps look into [PHP Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: Your LoginCheck.php page receives the $_POST data.  Ok, it checks in the database, if ok, I assume you use JavaScript to forward the user to Home.php.  you *could* add the values in a GET (Home.php?user=someguy).  But using a session is much better since there is not communication of valid data, just a session id.

Comment: I would like to pull more data from the database, WHERE UserLogin = user AND UserPassword = password and so on, so I can pull up their information for them to view

Comment: Then do that in Home.php.  Do not do it in LoginCheck.php and pass that information around.  Keep it within the server, do not trust your client to send you valid data from it's browser (read hacking!).

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left. You may need to use a browser, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with GrumpyCrouton's comment. POSTing to more than one page is hard to wrap my head around . . . would the user's browser then split in two? A different approach would be to POST to your LoginCheck.php and then that page would save the $_POST data to one or more $_SESSION values where they can be used by subsequent pages.

```
if ($authenticated) $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others stated, posting to two different pages is not the way to retrieve data after login check. We usually use `$_SESSION`. Read the [DOCS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

With that being said, I don't know whether you are using PDO or MySQli so I will just use MySQli for example.

Here's the easy/clean approach :

**form.php**

```
<form method ="POST" action="LoginCheck.php">
<div class="form-input">
    <b> User Name <b><br />
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" />
    <br />

    <b> Password <b><br />
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
    <br />
<input type="submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn-login"/>
</form>
```

**loginCheck.php**

```
    if (!empty( $_POST )) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {

    //post variables
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //check the database if there are records matching user info
    $stmt_invalidatepass = $conn->prepare("SELECT password,id FROM users 
    WHERE username=? ORDER BY dateCreated DESC LIMIT 1");
    $stmt_invalidatepass->bind_param("s",$user); 
    $stmt_invalidatepass->execute(); 
    $resultvvvid = $stmt_invalidatepass->get_result();
    $rowvalida = $resultvvvid->fetch_assoc();
    $checkPassword = $rowvalida['password'];

    //verify password
    $hash1_verified = password_verify($password, $checkPassword);

    if( ($hash1_verified==false)){

    //oops no result redirect to login.php

    }else{

    //found user
    //set in session
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $rowvalida['id'];

    //redirect to home.php
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit();
    }

}
}
```

**home.php**

```
// Always start this first
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();

} else {

//do user queries here

}
```